# parsing a binary file in C

Tags: c, parsing

I am trying to read a binary file for it's content
It has two sets of lines for each component
Second last character on the first line indicates the type of the component file (**^A** for assembly and **^B** for part)
If the type is **^A** I need to parse the file specified in next line which starts with **name^@**

```
àtype^@^Aà
name^@assembly1

àtype^@^Aà
name^@assembly2

àtype^@^Bà
name^@apart1

àtype^@^Bà
name^@apart2
```

When I try to parse this file, I can not read past the binary characters in the file.
First line contains a binary character (**à**) so I get an empty line. Second line has **^@** after name, so I only get 'name' and the len is 4.
This is my code snippet

```
FILE *fp;
  char line[256];
  fp = fopen(name, "rb");
  fgets(line, 256, fp);

  printf("line %s\n", line);
  printf("len %d\n\n", strlen(line));

  fgets(line, 256, fp);

  printf("line %s\n", line);
  printf("len %d\n\n", strlen(line));
```

This is the output

```
line 
len 0

line name
len 4
```

My aim is to parse the type of component (^A or ^B) and then get the name of the component.
Please help in pointing out how to solve this.

Comment: What on earth is a "binary character"? What's a "non-binary character", for that matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets` and most `<stdio.h>` functions work with **text**, not binary data.

The "character" `^@` has, I think, the binary value `0`, which messes up all the string handling functions.

You need to read character-by-character and/or not use string functions with objects containing embedded zero bytes.

Comment: Note that `fgets` reads all the bytes, including the `'\0'` and the following ones -- but, again, you cannot use string functions on that data. After you read the second line, `line[4]` is `0` but `printf("%s\n", line+5)` outputs `"assembly1"`.

Comment: Thanks pmg. Both the answer and this comment helped.